# mariadb.ProgrammingError: SQL syntax error INSERT INTO issue with (%s/?)

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I'm using python 3.9
and my sql server is on 10.3.29-MariaDB-0+deb10u1 Raspbian 10

I want to insert a single field into a new line in my sql database using python.

```
# python3!
import mariadb

mydb = mariadb.connect(
    host="***(just wanted to exclude the domain)",
    port=25555,
    user="test",
    password="test",
    database="test"
)
cursor = mydb.cursor()

first = "test5"
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO contacts (firstname) VALUES (%s)",
               first)

mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
mydb.close()
```

and I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\contact_test\contacts\tests.py", line 14, in <module>
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO contacts (firstname) VALUES (%s)",
mariadb.ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1
```

I have tried to variate between (%s) and (?) but it makes no difference.

When I try to use the same command directly within the database:

```
MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO contacts (firstname) VALUES ("test5");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.009 sec)
```

I become this output:

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT * FROM contacts;
+----+-----------+------------+---------+----------+----------+--------------+--------------+-------+
| id | firstname | secondname | sirname | landline | mobile   | mailaddress1 | mailaddress2 | group |
+----+-----------+------------+---------+----------+----------+--------------+--------------+-------+
|  . | ...       |            |         |          |          |              |              |     . |
|  6 | test5     |            |         |          |          |              |              |     0 |
+----+-----------+------------+---------+----------+----------+--------------+--------------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

so it worked.

***Update:***

I have also variated between:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (firstname) VALUES (%s)"
val = ("test5")

cursor.execute(sql, val)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\coding\contact\contacts_test\v1.0\test.py", line 14, in <module>
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO contacts (firstname) VALUES (%s)",
mariadb.ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1
```

and:

```
first = "test5"

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO contacts (firstname) VALUES (%s)",
               (first))
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\coding\contact\contacts_test\v1.0\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO contacts (firstname) VALUES (%s)",
mariadb.ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1
```

Comment: think `first` needs to be a tuple

Comment: `val = ("test5")` --> `val = ("test5",)`

Comment: @balderman thanks that solved my Problem

Answer (score 0):

***Solved:***

as suggested by [@balderman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415016/balderman) I have added the {,}:

```
first = "test7"
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO contacts (firstname) VALUES (%s)",
               (first,))
```

Python output:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

sql output:

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE firstname = 'test7';
+----+-----------+------------+---------+----------+--------+--------------+--------------+-------+
| id | firstname | secondname | sirname | landline | mobile | mailaddress1 | mailaddress2 | group |
+----+-----------+------------+---------+----------+--------+--------------+--------------+-------+
|  8 | test7     |            |         |          |        |              |              |     0 |
+----+-----------+------------+---------+----------+--------+--------------+--------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

so my problem is solved. Thanks to all how helped! :D